# Editing Java Web Application

Tags: java, web-applications, jar, war

I have a small workshop `"Modern Autos Workshop"` and i am managing my maintenance activities via a `Computerized Maintenance Management Software.` The application was developed by a freelancer and he simply gave me a windows installer `.EXECUTABLE` file. The application was designed on JAVA, in short, it was a DYNAMIC JAVA WEB DATABASE APPLICATION. Now i have changed the name of my workshop and i don't know how to change the name displayed on my software and invoices.
When i opened the installation directory, following folders were found:

```
 1= app (contains number of .jar files including "Modern Autos
    Workshop Run.jar" and a "Modern Autos Workshop.war" file)
        2= db (contains .DAT files)
        3= JRE 6 (contains lib folder)
        4= Jetty Temp (contains files extracted from .war file from 1= app folder)
        5= my db (contains lib folder)
        6= my db backup (contains lib folder)
        7= Modern Autos Workshop Run.jar file
```

i am not a programmer, but  please help me if some one can do this impossible thing..!

Comment: Did he give you the source code of your web application?

Comment: Java is a programming language that gets 'compiled' which means it is translated into machine code more or less. Without the original files it's rather difficult to edit any of the code to update it.

Comment: You may want to call the freelancer - if you're not a programmer diving into the guts of the program is going to be difficult to say the least (much the same as I would feel if I needed to rebuild a transmission). Sometimes paying the extra money is worth having it done by a professional.

Comment: Your only hope is that there's a database entry that allows you to modify content without having to repackage the app.  You need to contact him and ask for the source code.  I think it's yours by right, but it depends on the agreement you had with him when the app was developed.

Comment: Note that if you don't have the source code, you may want to look for a Java Decompiler.

Comment: @leigero: I can read a manual on how to replace a clutch assembly - I know how to use a wrench and various tools, but that doesn't mean I know how to replace the clutch. Having a non-programmer do a search and replace on a string could result in variables being renamed and having the entire application stop working.

Comment: Although this is almost certainly a pretty trivial change, as a non-programmer it is very easy to change the wrong thing and break the application. IMO the safest thing is just to have the original programmer modify it. The work should not take any longer than 5 minutes.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea For big projects, my guess would be that decompiled code would be rather difficult to make heads or tails of

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible using a decompiler to do what you are trying to do but it will be very hard unless you are an experienced developer.

If you have access to the original source code (at the very least it will have files called ".java" in it) then it is a bit easier but unless you already know the basics of programming it will not be trivial.

Ideally there will be a configuration file or database table that you can change so I would look for files with the extension "properties" or "txt" and also look in the database tables.

For an experienced developer (assuming they have the source code) it will be a very fast and easy job.

Comment: You can decompile an entire project back to source code and then rebuild the application from that. It's not a trivial job though.

Answer (score 0):

Without source code it will be quite difficult. You have to decompile byte code and then perform change and after that compile code again. Assuming you have all the tools, it can be quite complex even for skilled developers.

You can only analize your database if there is data which you can change. That change will be easy. Everything else is not easy, especially not for non-programmers.